# Nothing happens after deleting object from const WeakSet

Tags: ecmascript-6

I tried to run this code in Chrome Developer tools console and it went smooth. It is counterintuitive for me as when you're setting an object to `null`, you’re essentially deleting the it. But `const` should prevent it from being changed in any way.

```
   let obj1 = { id: 1};
   let obj2 = { id: 2};
   const ws = new WeakSet([obj1, obj2]);
   obj2 = null;
```

Is it expected behavior and I just don't understand something or it is the issue with the console and garbage collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** const means you can update the value of what the const is refering to, but you cannot reassign its reference to something else

```
const obj={id:1}
 obj.id=2 //no problem
 obj={id:3}//TypeError: Assignment to constant variable
```

I ran your code in [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/veyicotoye/edit?js,console)

```
let obj1 = { id: 1};
let obj2 = { id: 2};
const ws = new WeakSet([obj1, obj2]);


console.log(ws.has(obj2))
obj2 = null;
console.log(ws.has(obj2))
```

And here's the output:
`true
false`

This is the expected behavior, even with const. Because you're setting obj2 to null, not directly assigning vaue to ws which is const.

I was able to add new object obj3 to ws using `ws.add(obj3)`. Even this is valid.However, `ws=new Weakset([obj3])` will throw an exception.

> ES2015 const does not indicate that a value is ‘constant’ or
>   immutable. A const value can definitely change. The following is
>   perfectly valid ES2015 code that does not throw an exception:
>   `const foo = {}; foo.bar = 42; console.log(foo.bar); // → 42`
>   The only thing that’s immutable here is the binding. const assigns a value ({})
>   to a variable name (foo), and guarantees that no rebinding will
>   happen.

[Source](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-const)

Comment: @Maxim Kuleshjov does this help?